# Design pattern used in ExecutorCompletionService core java class

Tags: java, design-patterns

The ExecutorCompletionService is wrapper around the Executor and ExecutorService class. I can think of many design patterns by looking at the ExecutorCompletionService class source code

```
public class ExecutorCompletionService<V> implements CompletionService<V>
{
    public ExecutorCompletionService(Executor executor) {
    }
}
```

- Proxy Design pattern
- Adapter Design pattern
- Decorator Design pattern
- Bridge Design pattern

Can anyone explain in details which design pattern we can categorize this class implementation?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You've already identified the patterns. There's no reason a class can't be implemented by using more than one.

Comment: It's none of them - it's simply a compositional relationship. It seems to me that you need to read about the definitions of those patterns and try and understand their intent. For example, this absolutely cannot be a decorator - so the fact that you mention that pattern means that you haven't got a good understanding of these design patterns.

Comment: "_The ExecutorCompletionService is wrapper around the Executor_" - it's not. Is an implementation of `CompletionService` that uses an `Executor`.

Comment: I agree, but Logically ExecutorCompletionService look like the Wrapper around ExecutorService, Both has many common methods?

Comment: I'm not sure if 2 out of 12 counts as "many common methods". And it doesn't share *any*  method with `Executor`.

Comment: Thanks Mate, should be fine. So it is simply DI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ExecutorCompletionService` is not a wrapper around an `Executor`, it is an implementation of `CompletionService` which *uses*  an Executor to do its work.

That this `Executor` is injected through the constructor rather than created internally is an application of Dependency Inversion.

Similarly, it can also accept an external `BockingQueue`-implementation to be used for holding the completed tasks, but this doesn't make it a wrapper around a `BockingQueue`.